# Enable --color for eslint-loader

Tags: node.js, webpack, eslint, eslint-loader

How can i enable color for `eslint-loader's` console output?
When i run `eslint --color --quiet --cache --format=node_modules/eslint-formatter-pretty .` for example, the output will be colored with nice white/yellow/red/green colors.

I am trying to find a way to enable the same for webpack `eslint-loader`.
Here is my eslint rule:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  enforce: "pre",
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: "eslint-loader",
  options: {
    formatter: require("eslint-formatter-pretty"),
    failOnWarning: false,
    failOnError: true
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit late but what you can do is simply adding the option in the command line like so :

```sh
webpack --color
```

Cheers